# How does FEDEX Web Services work?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Any one help me to find the rate services using FedEx api? I have 3 files for finding rate service.

1. fedex-common.php5
2. RateWebServiceClient.php
3. RateService_v14.wsdl

I had Download all the three files from https://www.fedex.com/wpor/web/jsp/drclinks.jsp?links=wss/getstarted.html here. When i run RateWebServiceClient.php file then it shows a error:

> Code: 873
>   Message: All specified account numbers must match.

Please Help me to find the rate services. Here is the code which i used

1.fedex-common.php5

```
    <?php
// Copyright 2009, FedEx Corporation. All rights reserved.

define('TRANSACTIONS_LOG_FILE', '../fedextransactions.log');  // Transactions log file

/**
 *  Print SOAP request and response
 */
define('Newline',"<br />");

function printSuccess($client, $response) {
    echo '<h2>Transaction Successful</h2>';  
    echo "\n";
    printRequestResponse($client);
}

function printRequestResponse($client){
    echo '<h2>Request</h2>' . "\n";
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()). '</pre>';  
    echo "\n";

    echo '<h2>Response</h2>'. "\n";
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse()). '</pre>';
    echo "\n";
}

/**
 *  Print SOAP Fault
 */  
function printFault($exception, $client) {
    echo '<h2>Fault</h2>' . "<br>\n";                        
    echo "<b>Code:</b>{$exception->faultcode}<br>\n";
    echo "<b>String:</b>{$exception->faultstring}<br>\n";
    writeToLog($client);

    echo '<h2>Request</h2>' . "\n";
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()). '</pre>';  
    echo "\n";
}

/**
 * SOAP request/response logging to a file
 */                                  
function writeToLog($client){  
if (!$logfile = fopen(TRANSACTIONS_LOG_FILE, "a"))
{
   error_func("Cannot open " . TRANSACTIONS_LOG_FILE . " file.\n", 0);
   exit(1);
}

fwrite($logfile, sprintf("\r%s:- %s",date("D M j G:i:s T Y"), $client->__getLastRequest(). "\n\n" . $client->__getLastResponse()));
}

/**
 * This section provides a convenient place to setup many commonly used variables
 * needed for the php sample code to function.
 */
function getProperty($var){
    if($var == 'key') Return 'HxxJgDtsmXIZbKik'; 
    if($var == 'password') Return 'ZyZK1pBXkxtwchIYnVBU4Z56R'; 

    if($var == 'shipaccount') Return '510087208'; 
    if($var == 'billaccount') Return '510051408 '; 
    if($var == 'dutyaccount') Return ''; 
    if($var == 'freightaccount') Return '510087208';  
    if($var == 'trackaccount') Return '510087208'; 

    if($var == 'meter') Return '100179026 '; 

    if($var == 'shiptimestamp') Return mktime(10, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+1, date("Y"));

    if($var == 'spodshipdate') Return '2013-09-21';
    if($var == 'serviceshipdate') Return '2013-09-26';

    if($var == 'readydate') Return '2010-05-31T08:44:07';
    if($var == 'closedate') Return date("Y-m-d");

    if($var == 'pickupdate') Return date("Y-m-d", mktime(8, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y")));
    if($var == 'pickuptimestamp') Return mktime(8, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"));
    if($var == 'pickuplocationid') Return 'XXX';
    if($var == 'pickupconfirmationnumber') Return 'XXX';

    if($var == 'dispatchdate') Return date("Y-m-d", mktime(8, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y")));
    if($var == 'dispatchlocationid') Return 'XXX';
    if($var == 'dispatchconfirmationnumber') Return 'XXX';      

    if($var == 'tag_readytimestamp') Return mktime(10, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+1, date("Y"));
    if($var == 'tag_latesttimestamp') Return mktime(20, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+1, date("Y"));   

    if($var == 'expirationdate') Return '2013-05-24';
    if($var == 'begindate') Return '2013-04-22';
    if($var == 'enddate') Return '2013-04-25';  

    if($var == 'trackingnumber') Return 'XXX';

    if($var == 'hubid') Return 'XXX';

    if($var == 'jobid') Return 'XXX';

    if($var == 'searchlocationphonenumber') Return '5555555555';

    if($var == 'shipper') Return array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' => 'Sender Name',
            'CompanyName' => 'Sender Company Name',
            'PhoneNumber' => '1234567890'
        ),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('Address Line 1'),
            'City' => 'Collierville',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'TN',
            'PostalCode' => '38017',
            'CountryCode' => 'US',
            'Residential' => 1
        )
    );
    if($var == 'recipient') Return array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' => 'Recipient Name',
            'CompanyName' => 'Recipient Company Name',
            'PhoneNumber' => '1234567890'
        ),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('Address Line 1'),
            'City' => 'Herndon',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'VA',
            'PostalCode' => '20171',
            'CountryCode' => 'US',
            'Residential' => 1
        )
    );  

    if($var == 'address1') Return array(
        'StreetLines' => array('10 Fed Ex Pkwy'),
        'City' => 'Memphis',
        'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'TN',
        'PostalCode' => '38115',
        'CountryCode' => 'US'
    );
    if($var == 'address2') Return array(
        'StreetLines' => array('13450 Farmcrest Ct'),
        'City' => 'Herndon',
        'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'VA',
        'PostalCode' => '20171',
        'CountryCode' => 'US'
    );                    
    if($var == 'searchlocationsaddress') Return array(
        'StreetLines'=> array('240 Central Park S'),
        'City'=>'Austin',
        'StateOrProvinceCode'=>'TX',
        'PostalCode'=>'78701',
        'CountryCode'=>'US'
    );

    if($var == 'shippingchargespayment') Return array(
        'PaymentType' => 'SENDER',
        'Payor' => array(
            'ResponsibleParty' => array(
                'AccountNumber' => getProperty('billaccount'),
                'Contact' => null,
                'Address' => array('CountryCode' => 'US')
            )
        )
    );  
    if($var == 'freightbilling') Return array(
        'Contact'=>array(
            'ContactId' => 'freight1',
            'PersonName' => 'Big Shipper',
            'Title' => 'Manager',
            'CompanyName' => 'Freight Shipper Co',
            'PhoneNumber' => '1234567890'
        ),
        'Address'=>array(
            'StreetLines'=>array(
                '1202 Chalet Ln', 
                'Do Not Delete - Test Account'
            ),
            'City' =>'Harrison',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'AR',
            'PostalCode' => '72601-6353',
            'CountryCode' => 'US'
            )
    );
}

function setEndpoint($var){
    if($var == 'changeEndpoint') Return false;
}

function printNotifications($notes){
    foreach($notes as $noteKey => $note){
        if(is_string($note)){    
            echo $noteKey . ': ' . $note . Newline;
        }
        else{
            printNotifications($note);
        }
    }
    echo Newline;
}

function printError($client, $response){
    print_r($client);
    echo Newline;
    print_r($response);
    echo '<h2>Error returned in processing transaction</h2>';
    echo "\n";
    printNotifications($response -> Notifications);
    printRequestResponse($client, $response);
}

function trackDetails($details, $spacer){
    foreach($details as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value) || is_object($value)){
            $newSpacer = $spacer. '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            echo '<tr><td>'. $spacer . $key.'</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
            trackDetails($value, $newSpacer);
        }elseif(empty($value)){
            echo '<tr><td>'.$spacer. $key .'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>';
        }else{
            echo '<tr><td>'.$spacer. $key .'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

.....
..

My 2nd file is :

2.RateWebServiceClient.php

```
    <?php
// Copyright 2009, FedEx Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Version 12.0.0

require_once('../../library/fedex-common.php5');

$newline = "<br />";
//The WSDL is not included with the sample code.
//Please include and reference in $path_to_wsdl variable.
$path_to_wsdl = "../../wsdl/RateService_v14.wsdl";

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); // Refer to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php for more information

$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
    'UserCredential' =>array(
        'Key' => getProperty('key'), 
        'Password' => getProperty('password')
    )
); 
$request['ClientDetail'] = array(
    'AccountNumber' => getProperty('shipaccount'), 
    'MeterNumber' => getProperty('meter')
);
$request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => ' *** Rate Request v14 using PHP ***');
$request['Version'] = array(
    'ServiceId' => 'crs', 
    'Major' => '14', 
    'Intermediate' => '0', 
    'Minor' => '0'
);
$request['ReturnTransitAndCommit'] = true;
$request['RequestedShipment']['DropoffType'] = 'REGULAR_PICKUP'; // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShipTimestamp'] = date('c');
$request['RequestedShipment']['ServiceType'] = 'INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY'; // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackagingType'] = 'YOUR_PACKAGING'; // valid values FEDEX_BOX, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['TotalInsuredValue']=array(
    'Ammount'=>100,
    'Currency'=>'USD'
);
$request['RequestedShipment']['Shipper'] = addShipper();
$request['RequestedShipment']['Recipient'] = addRecipient();
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShippingChargesPayment'] = addShippingChargesPayment();
$request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'ACCOUNT'; 
$request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'LIST'; 
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackageCount'] = '1';
$request['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'] = addPackageLineItem1();



try {
    if(setEndpoint('changeEndpoint')){
        $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint('endpoint'));
    }

    $response = $client -> getRates($request);

    if ($response -> HighestSeverity != 'FAILURE' && $response -> HighestSeverity != 'ERROR'){      
        $rateReply = $response -> RateReplyDetails;
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr><td>Service Type</td><td>Amount</td><td>Delivery Date</td></tr><tr>';
        $serviceType = '<td>'.$rateReply -> ServiceType . '</td>';
        $amount = '<td>$' . number_format($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails[0]->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount,2,".",",") . '</td>';
        if(array_key_exists('DeliveryTimestamp',$rateReply)){
            $deliveryDate= '<td>' . $rateReply->DeliveryTimestamp . '</td>';
        }else if(array_key_exists('TransitTime',$rateReply)){
            $deliveryDate= '<td>' . $rateReply->TransitTime . '</td>';
        }else {
            $deliveryDate='<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        echo $serviceType . $amount. $deliveryDate;
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';

        printSuccess($client, $response);
    }else{
        printError($client, $response);
    } 

    writeToLog($client);    // Write to log file   
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
   printFault($exception, $client);        
}



function addShipper(){
    $shipper = array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' => 'Sender Name',
            'CompanyName' => 'Sender Company Name',
            'PhoneNumber' => '9012638716'
        ),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('Address Line 1'),
            'City' => 'Collierville',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'TN',
            'PostalCode' => '38017',
            'CountryCode' => 'US'
        )
    );
    return $shipper;
}
function addRecipient(){
    $recipient = array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' => 'Recipient Name',
            'CompanyName' => 'Company Name',
            'PhoneNumber' => '9012637906'
        ),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('Address Line 1'),
            'City' => 'Richmond',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'BC',
            'PostalCode' => 'V7C4V4',
            'CountryCode' => 'CA',
            'Residential' => false
        )
    );
    return $recipient;                                      
}
function addShippingChargesPayment(){
    $shippingChargesPayment = array(
        'PaymentType' => 'SENDER', // valid values RECIPIENT, SENDER and THIRD_PARTY
        'Payor' => array(
            'ResponsibleParty' => array(
                'AccountNumber' => getProperty('billaccount'),
                'CountryCode' => 'US'
            )
        )
    );
    return $shippingChargesPayment;
}
function addLabelSpecification(){
    $labelSpecification = array(
        'LabelFormatType' => 'COMMON2D', // valid values COMMON2D, LABEL_DATA_ONLY
        'ImageType' => 'PDF',  // valid values DPL, EPL2, PDF, ZPLII and PNG
        'LabelStockType' => 'PAPER_7X4.75'
    );
    return $labelSpecification;
}
function addSpecialServices(){
    $specialServices = array(
        'SpecialServiceTypes' => array('COD'),
        'CodDetail' => array(
            'CodCollectionAmount' => array(
                'Currency' => 'USD', 
                'Amount' => 150
            ),
            'CollectionType' => 'ANY' // ANY, GUARANTEED_FUNDS
        )
    );
    return $specialServices; 
}
function addPackageLineItem1(){
    $packageLineItem = array(
        'SequenceNumber'=>1,
        'GroupPackageCount'=>1,
        'Weight' => array(
            'Value' => 50.0,
            'Units' => 'LB'
        ),
        'Dimensions' => array(
            'Length' => 108,
            'Width' => 5,
            'Height' => 5,
            'Units' => 'IN'
        )
    );
    return $packageLineItem;
}
?>
```

If you have any other solution using any api in php is also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have signed up for a test key. So once you have that:

In the fedex-common.php file, you need to put in your key, password, account number, and meter number. You will see that there are multiple account numbers, like billaccount and dutyaccount, etc; just use the same account number on those.

Then on RateWebServiceClient.php, make sure the WSDL file is in the right place so that it can be loaded into the SoapClient class. Then go to the addShipper() and addRecipient() definition and put real addresses there. Once you have those in place, run RateWebServiceClient.php in your browser and you should be set.

Answer (score 2):

Error message is very clear:
`Code: 873 Message: All specified account numbers must match.`

In your fedex-common.php5 file you have:
 `if($var == 'shipaccount') Return '510087208';
 if($var == 'billaccount') Return '510051408 ';`

Those account numbers must match. 510087208 and 510051408 account numbers are different. Solution:
 `if($var == 'shipaccount') Return '510087208';
 if($var == 'billaccount') Return '510087208';`

Answer (score 1):

**"How does FEDEX Web Services work?"**

This is an unanswerable question. No one knows.